# Measuring the voltage drop across electrical components doesn't match the calculated values

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, oscilloscope, kirchhoffs-laws

I have a newbie question regarding circuit analysis.

I have a simple circuit with a voltage source of +4.32V (output of a u7805C voltage regulator), an 18K Ohm resistor, a normally open push button, and a 39K Ohm resistor.

The schematic of the circuit is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpSy7s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Below is a table comparing the calculated and simulated values vs the values measured with an oscilloscope.

[image]

When I measure the value across the 18KOhm resistor I get a 4.16V when the switch is open and closed. Shouldn't the measured voltage drop across the 18KOhm be the same as that in the simulation?

**EDIT and new findings**

This is the circuit, I am using a solderless breadboard. I am using a microcontroller development board's ([MSP430FR6989](https://www.ti.com/product/MSP430FR6989?keyMatch=MSP430FR6989&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=part-number)) to power the circuit, the **5V** and **GND** pins are connected to a [uA7805C](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs056p/slvs056p.pdf?ts=1590398944508) voltage regulator to

The schematic of the circuit is shown below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD5fnw.png)</sup>

Here is a picture of the circuit

[image]
[image]

---

Measuring the Voltage between the rails:

[image]
[image]

---

Measuring the output voltage of the regulator:

[image]
[image]

---

Measuring the voltage drop across the 18KOhm resistor:

[image]
[image]

---

However, I replaced development board power and replaced it with a 9V Alkaline Battery and I got different results get any issues:

[image]

These are the results:
[image]

I think the problem was with MSP430 powering the circuit, but that is what I don't understand I am using is only to power the circuit (5V power supply), and the voltage between the 5V pin and the GND pin was 5.12V

---

**I think I figured what the problem was**

I think the problem was the ground clip of the oscilloscope was connected to a point other than the ground of the circuit.

I connected it like that:

[image]

and I got these oscilloscope readings when the switch is open:

[image]

These are the oscilloscope readings when the switch is closed:

[image]

As mentioned the Oscilloscope's ground probe should only be connected to the ground, it is not like a multimeter where we can probe a voltage with reference to any other voltage point.

Comment: voltage _across_ a resistor in an open circuit is zero. are you sure you are not measuring it in proportion to ground ?

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad Yes I am sure, I am measuring the voltage across the R1 resistor

Comment: Do you get the same result by measuring the voltage with a multimeter?

Comment: @AliNategh I don't have a multimeter at the moment, but will it give a different result than the oscilloscope?

Comment: 4.32 volts coming from a 7805 - that doesn't sound right to me. Fix that first is my advice.

Comment: @Forat I think you should edit your post and provide images of your oscilloscope settings and the output that you are seeing.

Comment: @AliNategh I will do that

Comment: First rule of scope measurements: never ever move ground clip from circuit ground. While measuring across 18k you are shorting scope ground and PSU ground via mains earth PE.

Comment: @carloc thank you for the advice, I thought I could use the oscilloscope's ground clip with any electrical component not necessarily connected to ground

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Photo 1. (1) 5 V regulator with no decoupling capacitors! (2) Jumpers to (3) supply from a PCB.*

[image]

*Photo 2. (1) 5V and (2) GND. The guys in forensics lab reckon that the 5 V regulator is being fed from a 5 V supply. This won't work!*

Your regulator needs "headroom" to work. If you check the datasheet for your regulator you'll find that you need a minimum of about 7 V for the regulator to work. You've also omitted the decoupling capacitors (which for some reason many beginners feel are an optional extra) so the regulator may go into oscillation. Solution: remove the regulator and supply the breadboard directly from the PCB's 5V and GND terminals.

I can see a USB cable plugged into the board. This means that your breadboard has a ground reference to some external power-supply. If your 'scope is using the same ground reference then you must not connect the ground clip to anywhere other than the 0 V rail of your breadboard.

Comment: Yes I do see ripples on my scope and it needs decoupling capacitors, but how is that related to my problem, where Vmicro = 5.12V, V18kohm = 4.16V (when open or close). Also, I tried it without the regulator, I got the same problem. I tried it again but the ground clip is connected to the ground V18Kohm -> GND = 4.32V, Vsw->GND = 4.32V, but when I measure voltage drop across V18Kohm I get 4.16V.

This problem happened to me when I use the power supply of the microcontroller, and when I connect the scope's GND clip to somewhere other than the ground